# Reset Post IDs to less than 64bit integer

Tags: database, mysql

I have been running Wordpress for many years and have about 26000 posts.

At some point my post ids have exceeded a 32bit integer and I am now locked into using Wordpress on a 64 bit system.

I am seeing posts with IDs like 4863166253.

I would like to switch my hosting down to a low powered server like a raspberry pi which is 32bit.

Is there any way to reset the Post IDs so that they are all below 2 billion?

You can read my Wordpress bug report [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29917)

Thanks.

Comment: This is one of your plugins which drives you there, I would guess post_2_post but that is just a guess. You need to actually understand why you have such a high number (no real live amount of revisions will bring you there, unless again it is a plugin creating them) and only then you can start planning how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is the way I would take to solve the issue if I had to face it, it means is not *the* answer but one of the possibilities.

All the operations I will suggest should be run on a development/local server on a backup of database and not on production nor on original database.

If you have 26,000 posts but post id like 4,863,166,253 there are zillions of ids that are not used.

To solve this issue you need to:

### Step 1

- remove unused post ids. (trashed posts, revisions)
- removed *orphans* post meta entries
- remove *orphans* taxonomy relation entries

There are plugins for the scope, but it can be done using simple raw SQL queries.

### Step 2

Reset post ids changing them to start back from 1. This can be done using a combination of PHP + MySQL: if you retrieve post id column as an array (e.g. via `$wpdb->get_col()`), array keys (incremented by 1) would be new posts ids for posts whose current id is in array values.

Note that posts ids have to be changed in:

- post table
- taxonomy relation table
- post meta table

I suggest you run such a routine on subsets of posts using paginated results and not on thousands of rows at a whole.

### Step 3

[Set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql) on post table to post count + 1.

### Done

At the end of this process you higher post id should be easily inside the 32bit integer limit.

### Prevent post limit is reached again

- Disable post revisions or limit it in number (see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions#Revision_Options)).
- Move older posts (2 years old? 5?) to a separate blog on a multisite environment, e.g. `site1-archive.example.com` for posts in `site1.example.com`.

  This can be done using WordPress exporter with date range option.

  If you plan to do this,  is way better if done *before* resetting post ids (step #2 above), in this way both 2 blogs can have a lower post id.

  Of course after that you should also put in place a way to redirect *archived* post urls to new urls.